# Xamarin.Froms DatePicker dialogue color issue

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, datepicker, themes

I have a Xamarin.Forms app in which all color styles are working fine, in my App class I'm using (AppThemeBinding) in order to respond to the device's theme, but the Date Picker dialogue is not responding whatsoever. In light theme it is so normal, however in dark theme it shows a white background and the text is white.
[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB3zX.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gerald said that, it is known issue with Xamarin.Forms, but you can get workaround  from [[Bug] DatePicker theming issues with Android dark mode](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9033).

Don't define datePickerDialogTheme style in styles.xml, just use Visual="Material".

```
<DatePicker Visual="Material" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the Visual property didn't solve my problem, besides I wasn't setting any style for the picker dialogue.

Comment: @MuhammadRadwan I don't add any style for DatePicker, and set `DatePicker Visual="Material"`, test on Android Google Pixel 10.0, it works fine.

Comment: I see, anyways thanks for your suggestion, am afraid I will try something else

Answer (score 0):

This is a standing issue with Xamarin.Forms. You can see two issues for it:

- https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9033
- https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13178

They offer some workarounds that you might be able to use.

Comment: Ohh Mr. Gerald, nice to see you on Stackoverflow.. I'll check those, thanks for your help that means a lot to me!!

Comment: Actually one of the guys said that this bug only occurs with Datepicker and not Time picker, and yeah I've tried inserting a time picker and it was good

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance, please don't forget to mark a reply as an answer if you feel it helped you fix it :)

Comment: I'm sorry Gerald that I hadn't done it so far, coz I'm new to Stackoverflow, but I just did. I even got -4 for a question about visual studio mac ha ha ha

Answer (score 0):

In my case today on 06/28/2023 it was solved just by updating xamarin.forms.material version 5.0.0.2578 and xamarin.forms 5.0.0.2578 only that already worked dark theme

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).